# How to disable or shutdown NTP daemon?

Tags: pi-3, real-time, ntp, logfiles

I am running PI 3 as a standalone system. Therefore, it won't have internet connection and pi's date and time is manually set and Real Time Clock chip is used to keep the pi's date/time current. It works great. However, after running into unrelated system issues I was forced to carefully examine all the system logs in **/var/logs/**. I am surprised to find all kinds of error messages in those logs. Some of these system error messages are written to the log files almost every minute or once every hour. One of those error is `ntpd_intres[529]: host not found debian.pool.ntp.org`. I am sure this can't be good especially when the whole system is running on MicroSD card. I understand why NTP daemon is posting this message, but I would like to know if there is a way to turn it off or disable the NTP daemon completely?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you're looking for

```
systemctl disable systemd-timesyncd.service
```

I wouldn't worry about syslog trashing your SD card (it would take years if not decades), but disabling a service you don't need is generally a good idea.

You could also remove NTP completely if you're sure you don't need it:

```
apt-get remove ntp
```

It will be also be beneficial for your SD card since you won't be installing upgrades for that package anymore.